# codeigniter validating from textbox value(jquery) from array(php)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to validate whether my 3 input's are the same as the value in the array.

```php
<?php 
$aylength = 0;
$resultacyear = array();
foreach($academicyear->result() as $ay)
{
    $item = array(
            'tahunakademik' => $ay->Tahun_Akademik,
            'idsemester' => $ay->ID_Semester,
            'idlevelyear' => $ay->ID_Level_Year
            );
    $resultacyear[]= $item;
    $aylength++;
}

?>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btn_save').click(function() {
        <?php $inc = 0; ?>
        for(i=0;i<parseInt(<?php echo $aylength?>);i++)
        {
            if($('#txt_tahunAkademik').val()=="<?php echo $resultacyear[$inc]['tahunakademik'] ?>" && $('#cb_semester').val()=="<?php echo $resultacyear[$inc]['idsemester'] ?>" && $('#cmb_YearLevel').val()=="<?php echo $resultacyear[$inc]['idlevelyear'] ?>")
            {
                alert ("Data already exists!!");
                return false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                <?php $inc++; ?>
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

When i tried, it didn't validate or even checks the value.
Is something wrong with my validation??

Comment: Can't tell if you're improperly mixing php (server-side) and js (client-side) or I'm just too tired to follow your code. Sidenote, is it correct that you have an "and" in your if clause? Shouldn't it be an "or" ?

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JavaScript the way you are trying to. The loop in your javascript will not increment `$inc` as the PHP already is done serverside, before the JavaScript is presented to the client.